# Laravel save multiple records

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I've got an array within arrays and would like to add something to it.

```
$options = $request->options;
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $option['poll_id'] = $this->id;
}

dd($options);
```

But for some reason it does not add to the array.

So I receive this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "name" => "testtest"
  ]
]
```

But I would expect this:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "name"    => "testtest",
    "poll_id" => 1 

  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not changing `$options` so `foreach` is destroying `$option` with each iteration. Try something like this instead:

```
$options = [];
foreach ($request->options as $key => $value) {
    $options[$key]['poll_id'] = $this->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it using the `$key` attribute on arrays

```
// Suppose your $request->options is like:
$options = [
  0 => [
    "name" => "testtest"
  ]
];

foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
    $options[$key]['poll_id'] = 3; // Changing variable - $options here.
}
```

and it should work!

```
// $options would be like:

array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "testtest"
    "poll_id" => 3
  ]
]
```